# Jenkins can't copy file with fileExists to multiple directories

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a file in Jenkins credential manager that I would like to copy across several directories, if that folder exists.

However, the fileExists command seems to only work with one folder and no others. I have tried everything from using Java's file commands, using an absolute path nothing seems to work for me.

I tried pointing the environment variables on the same level as the directory to check, and inside the directory nothing seems to work.

```
dir("${DIRECTORY_PATH_NO_SPACES}"){
                    //checks to see if the folder in harris-gallery exists 
                    script {
                        if (fileExists("/project1"))
                        {
                            withCredentials([file(credentialsId: "${KEYSTORE_PROPERTIES_FILE_ID}", variable: 'FILE')]) {
                                bat("copy /y $FILE keystore.properties")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                dir("${WORKSPACE_PATH_NO_SPACES}"){
                    //checks to see if the folder in project2 exists      
                    script {
                        if (fileExists("/project2"))
                        {
                            withCredentials([file(credentialsId: "${KEYSTORE_PROPERTIES_FILE_ID}", variable: 'FILE')]) {
                                bat("copy /y $FILE keystore.properties")
                            }
                            bat("echo test")
                        }
                    }

                }


                dir("${DIRECTORY_PATH_NO_SPACES_project2_PROTOCOL}"){
                    //checks to see if the folder in project2 protocol exists  
                    script {
                        if (fileExists("/project3"))
                        {
                            withCredentials([file(credentialsId: "${KEYSTORE_PROPERTIES_FILE_ID}", variable: 'FILE')]) {
                                bat("copy /y $FILE keystore.properties")
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you are trying to check if `${DIRECTORY_PATH_NO_SPACES}/project1` exists but are in fact checking if `/project1` exists at the root of the machine and not in `DIRECTORY_PATH_NO_SPACES`.

I would try to check the full path "/${DIRECTORY_PATH_NO_SPACES}/project1"

Finally you could use plain batch here

```
                dir("${DIRECTORY_PATH_NO_SPACES}"){
                    //checks to see if the folder in harris-gallery exists 
                    script {
                            withCredentials([file(credentialsId: "${KEYSTORE_PROPERTIES_FILE_ID}", variable: 'FILE')]) {
                                bat("if exist /project1 copy /y $FILE keystore.properties")
                            }
                        }
                }
```